# Multi line SQL query in app.config file in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

How to store multi line SQL query in app.config file?

Below is example: I want to store this query in App.config file.

```
<add Key ="query" value="select * from users u LEFT join Employee E on u.id = E.id  Inner Join Department D on d.id=E.id
Left Join Orders O On O.Id = E.id
Inner Join Values V v.id = E.id 
WHERE u.createTime>=Getdate()-1 AND u.deletstatus=1
AND D.Id<>0"
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing??? Just write the whole query in one line

Comment: What error you getting?

Comment: You should't be storing SQL queries in the .config file in the first place.Create a stored procedure.The only SQL related item that should be stored in the .config file is the connection string to point to your SQL database

Answer (score 0):

The `web.config` and the `app.config` is an `xml` file, so you need to encode your parameter string.
In your case the symbols `<` and `>`  break's it.

To work must be as

```
<add Key ="query" value="select * from users u LEFT join Employee E on u.id = E.id  Inner Join Department D on d.id=E.id
Left Join Orders O On O.Id = E.id
Inner Join Values V v.id = E.id 
WHERE u.createTime&gt;=Getdate()-1 AND u.deletstatus=1
AND D.Id &lt;&gt; 0"   
... rest of parameters...
```